# Are large enough numbers the sum of two members of a dense, well-distributed set?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, additive-combinatorics, sumset

I have a set $S$ of positive integers, and would like to prove that all large enough $n$ are of the form $s+t$ with $s,t\in S.$ (In other words, $\mathbb{N} \setminus (S+S)$ is finite, where $+$ is the [sumset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset).) What techniques can I use to solve this sort of problem?

My particular example seems simple because not only is $S$ is dense
$$
\liminf_n\frac{\#\left(S\cap\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\right)}{n}>0
$$
but it has another largeness property (I don't know a name for this): for every residue class $a\pmod b$,
$$
\liminf_n\frac{\#\left(S\cap\{a,a+b,a+2b,\ldots,a+nb\}\right)}{a+nb}>0.
$$
Is this property sufficient? Given a set $S$, can a reasonable bound be given for the greatest integer not in $S+S$?

If the proof is easy, I'd be happy for just hints (it's nice to prove things for myself!). Otherwise I'd be happy with a reference.

Comment: It’s clear that the first condition alone is not enough: take $S$ to be the set of even positive integers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Right -- the set $S$ has the stronger condition, the first one being there only to clarify the second.

Comment: @Charles I doubt that the condition is strong enough to imply $S+S$ is cofinite.  My intuition is that you could choose a rapidly-growing sequence of values $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots$ and choose $S$ to avoid each $a_i$, by having $S \cap (1,a_1)$ be poorly distributed mod $a_1$, $S \cap (1,a_2)$ be well-distributed mod $a_1$ (and below) but poorly distributed mod $a_2$, etc.  I would think that as long as $a_i$ is sparse enough then you can force all of these to happen simultaneously, while still having enough freedom to make $S$ well-distributed overall (maybe by a randomized construction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two conditions you list are insufficient.  If $\alpha$ is irrational and $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of the real number $x$, then the set $A:=\{n \in \mathbb N: \{n\alpha\} \in (0,1/4)\}$ has $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|A\cap \{a+b,\dots, a+bn\}|}{n}= 1/4$ for every $a, b\in \mathbb N$, while $A+A$ is not cofinite. In fact, $A+A$ is contained in $\{n\in \mathbb N: \{n\alpha\} \in (0,1/2)\}$, which has asymptotic density $1/2$.